# Cannot find com.intuit.utils.OauthHelper class for Android application

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to integrate QuickBooks api into our android application.

Below link is for Java Web Application but I want to this `OauthHelper` class in my android application.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-Java/blob/master/QuickbooksV3API/src/main/java/com/intuit/utils/OauthHelper.java

I also saw developer site of Intuit but it does not help,

https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/825445-can-t-find-com-intuit-ia-connection-oauthhelper-class

Is there is a new way to do it or any latest jar file which contain `OauthHelper` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JAR File**

You have to add this jar **ipp-v3-java-devkit-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies**, you can download from this [link](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits).

**OauthHelper Class**

```
public class OauthHelper {

    public static String REQUEST_TOKEN_URL;
    public static String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL;
    public static String AUTHORIZE_URL;

    public OauthHelper() {

        REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = Constants.OAUTH_URL + "/oauth/v1/get_request_token";
        ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = Constants.OAUTH_URL + "/oauth/v1/get_access_token";
        AUTHORIZE_URL = Constants.APPCENTER_URL + "/Connect/Begin";
    }

    public void getDynamicConsumer() {

        try {

            final String apptoken = Constants.APP_TOKEN;

            final URL url = new URL(Constants.OAUTH_URL
                    + "/oauth/v1/create_consumer?appToken=" + apptoken);
            final HttpURLConnection httpconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            httpconnection.connect();

            StringBuffer responseBody = null;
            int read = 0;
            final byte buffer[] = new byte[8192];
            String consumerret = "";
            String consumerkeytoken = "";
            String consumerkeysecret = "";

            try {
                final InputStream responseBodyStream = httpconnection
                        .getInputStream();
                responseBody = new StringBuffer();

                while ((read = responseBodyStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    responseBody.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
                }
                responseBodyStream.close();
                consumerret = responseBody.toString();

                final String[] consumerkey = consumerret.split("&");

                for (int i = 0; i < consumerkey.length; i++) {
                    final String[] currentElements = consumerkey[i].split("=");

                    if (currentElements[0].equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token")) {
                        consumerkeytoken = currentElements[1];
                    } else if (currentElements[0]
                            .equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token_secret")) {
                        consumerkeysecret = currentElements[1];
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex1) {

                final int httpRespCode = httpconnection.getResponseCode();
                try {
                    final InputStream es = httpconnection.getErrorStream();
                    final StringBuffer errorBody = new StringBuffer();
                    while ((read = es.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        errorBody.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex2) {
                    ex2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex3) {
            ex3.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getRequestTokenSignPost() {

        String authURL = null;

        OAuthProvider provider = createProvider();

        String consumerkey = Constants.CONSUMER_KEY;
        String consumersecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET;

        String callback_url = Constants.CALLBACK_URL;// WebUtils.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL;

        OAuthConsumer ouathconsumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumerkey,
                consumersecret);

        try {
            HttpParameters additionalParams = new HttpParameters();
            additionalParams.put("oauth_callback",
                    URLEncoder.encode(callback_url, "UTF-8"));
            ouathconsumer.setAdditionalParameters(additionalParams);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String requestret = "";
        String requestToken = "";
        String requestTokenSecret = "";

        try {
            String signedRequestTokenUrl = ouathconsumer
                    .sign(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL);

            URL url;

            url = new URL(signedRequestTokenUrl);

            HttpURLConnection httpconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            httpconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpconnection
                    .setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml");
            httpconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
            if (httpconnection != null) {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        httpconnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);

                }
                rd.close();
                requestret = sb.toString();
            }
            String[] requestTokenSections = requestret.split("&");

            for (int i = 0; i < requestTokenSections.length; i++) {
                String[] currentElements = requestTokenSections[i].split("=");

                if (currentElements[0].equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token")) {
                    requestToken = currentElements[1];
                } else if (currentElements[0]
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("oauth_token_secret")) {
                    requestTokenSecret = currentElements[1];
                }
            }

            Map<String, String> requesttokenmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            try {
                authURL = provider.retrieveRequestToken(ouathconsumer,
                        callback_url);
            } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ouathconsumer.setTokenWithSecret(ouathconsumer.getToken(),
                    ouathconsumer.getTokenSecret());

            requesttokenmap.put("requestToken", requestToken);
            requesttokenmap.put("requestTokenSecret", requestTokenSecret);
            requesttokenmap.put("authURL", authURL);
            return requesttokenmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static OAuthProvider createProvider() {
        OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
                OauthHelper.REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, OauthHelper.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
                OauthHelper.AUTHORIZE_URL);

        return provider;
    }

    public String getAuthorizeURL(String requestToken, String requestTokenSecret) {

        String authorizeURL = "";
        try {
            authorizeURL = AUTHORIZE_URL + "?oauth_token=" + requestToken;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return authorizeURL;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getAccessToken(String verifierCode,
            String requestToken, String requestTokenSecret) {
        String consumerkey = Constants.CONSUMER_KEY;
        String consumersecret = Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET;
        String accessToken = "";
        String accessTokenSecret = "";

        try {
            OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(consumerkey,
                    consumersecret);
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(requestToken, requestTokenSecret);

            HttpParameters additionalParams = new HttpParameters();
            additionalParams.put("oauth_callback", "oob");
            additionalParams.put("oauth_verifier", verifierCode);
            consumer.setAdditionalParameters(additionalParams);

            String signedURL = consumer.sign(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL);
            URL url = new URL(signedURL);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");

            String accesstokenresponse = "";
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
                accesstokenresponse = sb.toString();
            }
            if (accesstokenresponse != null) {
                String[] responseElements = accesstokenresponse.split("&");
                if (responseElements.length > 1) {
                    accessToken = responseElements[1].split("=")[1];
                    accessTokenSecret = responseElements[0].split("=")[1];
                    Map<String, String> accesstokenmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    accesstokenmap.put("accessToken", accessToken);
                    accesstokenmap.put("accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret);
                    return accesstokenmap;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Constants Class**

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String APP_TOKEN = ""; // First three credentials are from **Production** part not from **Development** part
    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "";

    public static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token";
    public static final String AUTH_URL = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin";
    public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token";

    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "oauthflow-quickbooks";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";

    public static final String CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://"
            + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
    public static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "quickbooks";

    public static String OAUTH_URL = "https://oauth.intuit.com";
    public static String APPCENTER_URL = "https://appcenter.intuit.com";

}
```

**Manifest file**

Add following intent filter to activity when login is initiated.

```
   <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="oauthflow-quickbooks" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: is this answer still valid? I want to try the same but the link given is invalid now